# How do I copy a specific number of directories with rsync?

Tags: rsync

I have a folder say `/media/Movies/English/` numbers of folders, there is say 500 folder

Now I want to copy only 50 folders, not in alphabetical order but in random  ...

How to do perform this task using rsync?

I tried the following `rsync` command

this is want happened `rsync -arv --include-from=/media/Movies_NTFS/Movies/English/rsync-test /home/joe/Videos/`

`rsync-test` file contains per line folders present in `/media/Movies_NTFS/Movies/English/` folder but nothing is copied, when I ran the command. why?

Comment: You need something like `rsync -arv --include-from=rsync-test /media/Movies/English /home/joe/Videos`, i.e. you are missing the source argument.

Comment: Solved it by using --files-from instead --inlcude-from ...

Comment: Good for you! I hope you're aware of the awesome tool called `unsort` for shuffling the folders (and use the `-r` option to make it even more random).

Answer (score 2):

OP solved question using the `--files-from` switch in `rsync` instead of `--include-from`.